# ¿Como dar click en un menuIten automáticamente cuando se abra el DrawerLayout?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, click, menu

¿Cómo puedo simular un clic a un item de un `Drawerlayout`?
Lo que quiero es que una vez desplegado el menú automáticamente se de clic a un item en específico, hay alguna función para eso?
Intente con `.performClick()` y marcó error.

Este es código dentro de mi método `onCreate()`

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_usuario_pdv, R.id.nav_ventas, R.id.nav_sesion,).setOpenableLayout(drawer).build();

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,mAppBarConfiguration);

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Quiero que al desplegar el drawer con

```
drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Se de click automáticamente en el 2do item

o si hay alguna otra forma por favor

Comment: Si, claro que hay funciones, pero deberías mostrarnos un poco de tu código para ver que estas haciendo. Segundo, deberías aclarar si tu drawerLayout es el que genera Android Studio como plantilla o es que tu creaste uno aparte.

Comment: Mi drawerlayout es generado por Android Studio

Comment: Ajá, ¿Y si nos muestras un poco de tu código?

Comment: El error seguramente marca porque aún no esta completamente abierto el Drawer y tal vez las referencias  a sus vistas que contiene no existen, recuerda siempre agregar los errores que tengas a tus preguntas. Agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar esto, puedes detectar cuando el `DrawerLayout` se encuentre completamente abierto, entonces llamar `.performClick()`, usa [DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener) y su método [onDrawerOpened()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener#onDrawerOpened(android.view.View)).

> [onDrawerOpened()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener#onDrawerOpened(android.view.View)) : lamado cuando el `Drawer` se ha asentado en un
> estado completamente abierto. El `Drawer` es interactivo en este
> punto.

Ejemplo:

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

 drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
         //* Drawer fue abierto, aquí llama tu método para dar clic a la vista.
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```